# StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, .. - Instagram Login

Tags: c#, https, request, http-post, instagram

#### Problem

```
StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, ...
```

My hypothesis is now that Instagram blocks such requests for security reasons.

---

#### Source Code

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    Console.Write("Username: ");

    string username = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Password: ");

    string password = Console.ReadLine();

    string postData = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AcmeInc/1.0)");

    var postResult = await client.PostAsync("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",new StringContent(postData, new UTF8Encoding()));

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine(postResult);
    Console.WriteLine("");
```

Comment: If by "such requests" you mean "requests not made from a  browser" then nobody has the capability to block them except for with a cooperative browser plugin of some kind. It's more likely that you're missing some kind of cookie or anti-forgery token, or just some header that the browser normally sends but you don't. Is there any reason why you don't just use Instagram's API?

Comment: Yes, because I do not want to have a Facebook or Instagram account. I have a question: Could you change the code that contains the cookie and anti-forgery token set for me?

Comment: That would be a pleasure.

Comment: 'I do not want to have a Facebook or Instagram account' - but you posted a login method to instagram. What did i miss?

Comment: 'Could you change the code that contains the cookie and anti-forgery token set for me?' If you have trouble doing this, please open another question. And please: SO is not a code writing service. You asked kindly, but this is still off-topic and against the rules.

Comment: I have an Instagram account, but I do not want to open a developer account.

Comment: I have to wait 90 minutes to post a new question. Could you please modify the source code for me? That would be a pleasure

Comment: _" Could you change the code that contains the cookie and anti-forgery token set for me?"_ - I never said that Instagram is specifically using these, they are examples of techniques that some websites employ. You have to do the investigation to find out what techniques Instagram uses by yourself.

Comment: I have already searched a lot but didn't find the good answer to the problem.

Comment: Sure, you're searching. Most people won't be doing what you're doing because most people will just use the API. As a programmer you're going to come up against situations that most people don't by nature of you doing something different. A better approach than searching is to analyse what the requests to and from Instagram in the browser look like.

Comment: And I want to stress that an HTTP client doesn't have something like `EnableAntiForgeryToken();` for you to call. The reason is that this is an implementation detail specific to the website you're visiting.

Comment: I have been working in computer science for years and know which view I should take of these problems. I also analyzed the network, where the logon credentials arrive at. `And I want to stress that an HTTP client doesn't have something like EnableAntiForgeryToken();` -  I know that there are no such methods because every website has almost different properties.

Comment: `Most people won't be doing what you're doing because most people will just use the API. As a programmer you're going to come up against situations that most people don't by nature of you doing something different` - I also find it better to deal with such situations from a psychological point of view, as it is much easier to solve problems in the future.

Comment: Now we come back to the topic, my hypothesis is that such requests are blocked by the Instagram server for security reasons.

Comment: That's probably true, but as I said before, it's impossible for them to actually know how you are making your request. All they get is the headers and the request body (if there is one). Therefore, the logical conclusion is that you need to make your request look exactly like theirs. If it includes anti-forgery tokens etc, then you'll need to grab those from the previous page load and supply them with your request. It can be tricky if the token is generated with Javascript though.

Comment: A new CSRF token is generated in each new request to the Instagram server, but I am currently trying to do it with only one. By the way, have a look at the new question I asked.